Jupyter notebook kernel (on VSCode) crashes after I run sklearn's KernelPCA
I'm working on Windows WSL2 and I'm trying to make a KPCA+LDA classifier using sci-kit learn's models. I'm using SIFAR-10 and I've tried a simple KPCA and it keeps crashing the kernel.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA, KernelPCA
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, confusion_matrix

When I load this libraries I get this warning:
2024-12-21 15:51:10.904015: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:477] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
E0000 00:00:1734789070.978347   25227 cuda_dnn.cc:8310] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
E0000 00:00:1734789071.000228   25227 cuda_blas.cc:1418] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-12-21 15:51:11.197131: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

# Load data
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
x_val = x_train[40000:, :].astype(np.float64)
x_train = x_train[:40000, :].astype(np.float64)
x_test = x_test[:].astype(np.float64)
y_val = np.squeeze(y_train[40000:]).astype(np.int8)
y_train = np.squeeze(y_train[:40000, :]).astype(np.int8)
y_test = np.squeeze(y_test[:]).astype(np.int8)

# Preprocessing data
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], -1)) # -1 makes the computer calculate the corresponding dimension based on the other given dimensions.
x_val = np.reshape(x_val, (x_val.shape[0], -1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], -1))

# Normalize between [-1, 1]
x_train = (x_train/256)*2 - 1
x_val = (x_val/256)*2 - 1
x_test = (x_test/256)*2 - 1

%%time
# Kernel PCA
rbf_kpca = KernelPCA(n_components=50, kernel='rbf', fit_inverse_transform=False, gamma=0.001)
rbf_kpca.fit(x_train)

After 1.5 minute the kernel crashes.
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the current cell or a previous cell. 
Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. 
Click here for more info. 
View Jupyter log for further details.

------------- LOG ---------------------
15:30:41.941 [error] Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: undefined, Reason: 2024-12-21 15:26:28.940879: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:477] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
E0000 00:00:1734787589.013841   22447 cuda_dnn.cc:8310] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
E0000 00:00:1734787589.034524   22447 cuda_blas.cc:1418] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-12-21 15:26:29.223378: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

Seeing the log I figured that it has something to do with tensorflow, cuda and cudnn compatibility and I realised that tensorflow doesn't recognise my GPU. So I cleared everything and did a clean reinstallation of Cuda 12.6, cuDNN 9.6 and the most recent nvidia drivers and after that TensorFlow did recognise my GPU when I run the session. But it still crashed.
Firstly, I was using 2000 components and I thought maybe it's a heavy load situation, so I reduced components to 50, but still crashed.
Then I thought, I'm using sklearn's library so what are tensorflow and cudnn doing here? I tried to disable GPU with
import os 
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"

import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

GPU was disabled, tensorflow didn't see it as 'available' but it still crashed and gave me the same log.
I don't understand what's going on. Especially since I don't even use tensorflow in this problem.

To help home in on the problem, try replacing kernel PCA with regular PCA and seeing if it still crashes. Also, use Windows Task Manager to track RAM usage - if it's climbing to the max before the crash occurs, it could be a RAM issue. Try using fewer samples and seeing if that causes the same problem. Once you identify the problem you can try some work-arounds. I suspect kernel PCA is the problem since it'll want to build a matrix sized n_samples x n_samples. You're right that sklearn does not use the GPU; it is CPU-only (as an aside, consider scikit-learn-intelex for faster computation).
